# Why does my count function only count as high as one when I have multiple integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Q: Why does my count function only count as high as one when I have multiple integers?

CODE:

```
import random

while True:
    value = 0
    count = 0
    right_counter = 0
    value = int(input("Enter the amount of questions would you like to answer: "))   
    AVG = right_counter / value
    if 0<=value<=10:
        for i in range(value):
            numb1 = random.randint(0, 12)
            numb2 = random.randint(0, 12)
            answer = numb1 * numb2
            AVG = right_counter / value



            problem = input("What is " + str(numb1) + " * " + str(numb2) + "? ")


            right_counter =+ 1


            if int(problem) == answer:
                print("You are Correct! Great Job!".format(right_counter))



            elif int(problem) > answer:
                print("Incorrect, Your answer is too high!")        


            elif int(problem) < answer:
                print("Incorrect, your answer is too low!")


        print("You got",right_counter,"out of",value,"correct, giving you an average of ",AVG,"")
        break


    else:
        print(" Error, Please type a number 1-10 ")
```

This is what the output looks like:

Enter the amount of questions would you like to answer: 3
What is 1 * 8? 8
You are Correct! Great Job!
What is 11 * 11? 122
Incorrect, Your answer is too high!
What is 1 * 7? 7
You are Correct! Great Job!
You got 1 out of 3 correct, giving you an average of  0.3333333333333333

I found some help on [Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html), but I couldn't answer my question.

Comment: The answers below all pointed out three separate bugs, so don't miss any of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bug:

```
right_counter =+ 1
```

This is (insidiously) equivalent to

```
right_counter = 1
```

you probably meant

```
right_counter += 1
```

You probably also want to address the logic issue that `right_counter` is incremented regardless of the correctness of the answer.

Comment: Tested it and you are physic, I moved some things around and implemented += 1.